# How can I decide on taking four classes for first year in graduate school?

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, coursework

I just finished undergraduate degree from a mediocre liberal arts college. I am attending a graduate school ranked about 30. I feel that I am lacking a little in my basic knowledge. Therefore, I was thinking about taking three to four classes in basic subjects (two semesters each of algebra, real analysis, complex analysis and algebraic topology) during my first year.

Coming from a liberal arts college, I have never taken four classes in a single semester and my plan is to do exactly that for two consecutive semesters.

If it helps, those four classes would be 16 credits in a semester. Algebra and analysis are 5.0 credits each. Complex analysis and algebraic topology are 3.0 credits each.

Also I am on a fellowship for first year of my graduate school, which means I do not have to teach and can dedicate my time for studies.

How can I approach this decision? What aspect may I not have taken into account?

Comment: At my school, full-time grad students take three courses (the equivalent of 9 credits, or 10 if there's one class with a lab component). Taking four in a semester is uncommon.

Comment: If it helps, those four classes would be 16 credits in a semester. Algebra and Analysis are 5.0 credits each. Complex Analysis and Algebraic Topology are 3.0 credits each.

Comment: My opinion: Don't take 4; you risk early burnout like I did.  Take 3 (or only 2 if possible), and focus on those subjects so that you can pass the prelims. It's great that you want a solid background in multiple areas (this is what the prelim system is designed for), but in reality you're not going to use most of it in your research.

Comment: It's an excellent question. Since it depends a lot on individual factors, and the structure of the program in question, I recommend that you address it to the graduate director, and/or other faculty members, at the university where you will be attending. Good luck!

Comment: Totally suggest the above by @Anonymous. And if you do talk to someone in the program, make sure that they give you the correct information about what "full-time" enrollment is.

Comment: You might, but most people would suggest that you don't. Graduate course loads (in the US) tend to be lighter than undergraduate course loads by one to two classes per semester. You will likely have many other responsibilities as a graduate student that are more important than getting through classes quickly.

Comment: @David I am on a fellowship for first year of my graduate school, which means I do not have to teach and can dedicate my time for studies.

Comment: @HumbleStudent If your graduate program is anything like the norm, then classroom time should not be a major priority of yours. You will probably be better served by trying out a few potential research advisors, or getting started on reading into the literature around your chosen research field than will additional courses. Additional classes for the sake of more breadth is not valuable for you at this point- your undergraduate degree has given you a reasonable breadth education. Pick up topics and classes when you need them- it's time to start going deep.

Comment: @HumbleStudent Which country is this in?

Comment: Standard advice for PhD students in my (CS) department is to **never** take more than two "real" classes a semester; if you have extra time, or you need more credit hours in your schedule, spend it on independent study/research/advisor-hunting.

Comment: @owjburnham I am in the United States

Comment: Looking back at my own experience, I took 4 courses during my second semester of grad school, for approximately the same reasons as OP, and it turned out to be the right decision. I'm not sure whether doing so is a  good idea for OP, but I don't believe that it's obviously a bad one.

Answer (score 8):

In the U.S., to have a fellowship as opposed to teaching assistantship really does free up considerable time each week, so four classes rather than the norm of three is completely plausible, *if* that's the way you decide to go.

I would want to strongly disagree with some of the claims, in comments above, that you'll never use most of the Prelim-level material "in your research". This is not *naturally* true, but can certainly be *made* true by being sufficiently ignorant, and/or sufficiently misconstruing the material in the Prelims and corresponding courses. (Also, one may encounter caricatures of Prelim exams.)

I would also strongly disagree with the claim that a (typical) undergrad degree in math (in the U.S.) provides sufficient breadth. This is even more crazily false than the supposed irrelevance of Prelim exam material. But, as with most things, clever people can contrive arguments for or against almost anything.

The genuine question is whether you *should* do four "core" courses, rather than take "electives", and/or self-study or group-study. First, this obviously depends on how effective/disciplined you are at self-study. If "very", then this is probably optimal to some degree, because it can be more flexibly scheduled, if nothing else. If you do better in a group setting, or with an instructor organizing things and making a schedule, then coursework might be better.

But there does remain the question of whether or not to try to do all the basic things (by which I don't mean standard U.S. undergrad math) prior to everything else. I generally don't think this is a good idea. Instead of all four basic grad courses, maybe do three and an "elective" in the/a direction of your curiosity. Maybe with less homework, and less "adversarial" feeling.

Over the years, I have seen many people "get tired" from (arguably over-assigned) homework, to the point that they have forgotten why they came to grad school, have forgotten their affection for math, and have lost a sense of genuine curiosity, from being "over-driven".

For that matter, much of the "basic" material is deemed essential-for-everyone (not only for general cultural sense, but) because it comes up all the time. (Sure, there is tradition, too, whose inertia sometimes swamps sense.) If/when people (especially novices, e.g, grad students) tell you that you "don't need to know" various things, you really should not believe them too strongly (because they probably don't know what they're talking about, or else, if nothing else, they'd have subtler opinions about it), even if they are your friends and/or peers.

It is true that thinking in terms of "research", especially if this means something opposite to the artificially over-ordered world-view of textbooks and established curriculum (and grades, and schedules), is a very good thing. Genuine mathematics is not as highly ordered/structured as one might imagine from textbooks and standardized course concepts. Nor are the questions/issues at the end of any particular chapter, so that one knows the relevant theorems! It is also not "graded". So, yes, experiencing something opposite to classwork is very good... but this is absolutely not an either/or.

That is, whether you acquire basics by self-study or guided study or coursework, that is just one thread. There is at least one other, the one where *you* make the decisions, based on your curiosity, etc, and are not graded or judged. We can call this "research", but that word has much other baggage these days, which is not immediately relevant to the practice of mathematics.

Comment: I will certainly discuss this topic with advisers in the department once I get there. I might go with three classes and if I have time left, I might go for self-study. 

I have had 6 reading courses in my previous Liberal Arts Colleges and would like to believe that I am self-motivated and disciplined. Therefore, self-studying might not be that bad (Finding a couple of friends to accompany me will be even better).. Thank you for your valuable insight.